# Gradle DSL Method not found: testCompile()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle

Hi I am working on a project and have reached a stage where it would be unwise to continue without unit testing. I thought unit testing in Android Studio would be straight forward but I can't run my tests.

Here are my dependencies. Everything works fine until I add the last line of code. I then receive the error message that is in the title.

[image]

How do I fix this and run my tests?

Here was the tutorial I was following: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: what's your android build tools version? It is usually specified in the root `build.gradle` file. Something like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`

Comment: It is always unwise to start a software project without writing unit tests first :-) Good luck with your issue.

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'. . What I said wasn't fully correct. We always had unit tests but could never run them.

Answer (score 4):

Official Unit testing support was introduced in Android plugin starting from version 1.1. This means that `testCompile` configuration is not available on previous versions. Based on your comment, you are using Android Gradle plugin version 1.0.0. That's why your build complains about missing `testCompile` configuration.

As of today, the latest released Android Gradle plugin version is `1.3.0`, so I would suggest moving to this version ASAP.

What you need to do - is in root level `build.gradle` file update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version to `1.3.0`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was solved by commenting out the following line in the top-level `build.gradle`:

```
testCompile() "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2"
```