# Android Studio update - Failed to resolve com.android.databinding

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated my JAVA to 1.8 version and also made android studio updates and gradle plugin updates as well. After the update i get following error in one of my module's(i.e. facebook module) build.gradle file on compiling my project:

[image]

My project level build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also there are few Symbol not found error like Cannot resolve Symbol 'GradleScriptException' and Cannot resolve symbol 'MavenDeployment' in facebook module build.gradle file. The full code of facebook buil.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    // Facbook Dependancies
    testCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    // Unit Tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
    def powerMockVersion = '1.6.1'
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powerMockVersion" testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:$powerMockVersion" testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:$powerMockVersion" androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$powerMockVersion" androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    // Connected Tests
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            project.version = matcher[0][1]
            return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
        throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'Facebook Platform License'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    // JDK 1.8 is more strict then 1.7. Have JDK 1.8 behave like 1.7 for javadoc generation
    if (org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaVersion() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    }
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

Clicking on `Upgrade plugin and sync project` does not do anything.

I have tried "Invalidate cache and restart" as suggested by various sources but it didn't work. I already have mentioned the latest version of gradle plugin in my project build.gradle.

I have gone through [Gradle DSL Method not found: testCompile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893008/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-testcompile)  but it does not resolve my issue.

What should i do to remove this compile error?

TIA

EDIT 1:
I made the change as suggested by sm4, And this DSL method not found error went off but now it fails to compile with the following error:

[image: Compile error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def powerMockVersion = '1.6.1'
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powerMockVersion" testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:$powerMockVersion" testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:$powerMockVersion" androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$powerMockVersion" androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
// Connected Tests
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

The `testCompile` is actually a call to a method. Because you have multiple `testCompile` on one line, it is being treated as a call to a method with many parameters. Such method does not exist.

Keep only one definition per line and it should work:

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powerMockVersion"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:$powerMockVersion"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:$powerMockVersion"
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$powerMockVersion"
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

Comment: Thnx. It worked. But there is another error that popped up. @sm4  Please have a look at the edit i made in question.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the fix mentioned by @sm4 i resolved the initial issue that i mentioned but it created another issue written in EDIT 1 section of question.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34834772/revisions) and then finally my project got compiled without any error.